# Restricting User Access to Specific Data in Power BI: How to Apply RLS Filters to a Particular Page Only?

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI, we need to restrict specific users from accessing data belonging to other users. To achieve this, we have implemented Row-Level Security (RLS). However, an issue has arisen where the RLS filters applied affect all the pages in the dashboard, whereas our intention is to have the access-based filters (RLS filters) only impact a particular page, rather than the entire dashboard. Is there any way for us to accomplish this?

We implemented Row-Level Security (RLS) in Power BI to restrict certain users from viewing other user's data. However, when we applied the RLS filters, it affected all the pages in the dashboard instead of just the specific page we intended. We were expecting the access-based filters (RLS filters) to only impact the particular page, while leaving the rest of the dashboard unaffected.

Comment: Does this answer you question : [Ignore RLS security on one page of the report](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Ignore-RLS-security-on-one-page-of-the-report/td-p/1168389)